# Time difference between rows in R dplyr, different units

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, difference

Here is my example. I am reading the following file: [sample_data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ourcnzoyzpsb69s/test.csv?dl=0)

```
library(dplyr)

txt <- c('"",  "MDN",                  "Cl_Date"',
          '"1",  "A",  "2017-04-15 15:10:42.510"',
          '"2",  "A",  "2017-04-01 14:47:23.210"',
          '"3",  "A",  "2017-04-01 14:49:54.063"',
          '"4",  "B",  "2017-04-30 13:25:00.000"',
          '"5",  "B",  "2017-04-03 17:53:13.217"',
          '"6",  "B",  "2017-04-15 15:17:43.780"')

ts <- read.csv(text = txt, as.is = TRUE)
ts$Cl_Date <- as.POSIXct(ts$Cl_Date)
ts <- ts %>% group_by(MDN) %>% arrange(Cl_Date) %>%
  mutate(time_diff = c(0,diff(Cl_Date)))
ts <-ts[order(ts$MDN, ts$Cl_Date),]
```

As a result I have

```
MDN Cl_Date         time_diff
A   4/1/2017 14:47  0
A   4/1/2017 14:49  2.514216665
A   4/15/2017 15:10 20180.80745
B   4/3/2017 17:53  0
B   4/15/2017 15:17 11.89202041
B   4/30/2017 13:25 14.92171551
```

So I group by MDN column and compute difference between Cl_Date column. As you can see sometime different in minutes (group A) and sometime difference in days (group B).

Why is time difference in different units and how to correct it?

P.S. I could not reproduce the same example with manual `data.frame` creation, so I had to read from file.

**UPDATE 1** 
`diff(ts$Cl_Date)` seems to be consistent, everything is in minutes. Does something break within `dplyr`?

**UPDATE 2**

```
ts <- ts %>% group_by(MDN) %>% arrange(Cl_Date) %>%
  mutate(time_diff_2 = Cl_Date-lag(Cl_Date))
```

produces the same result.

Comment: Why don't you use an easily reproducible example like `df <- data.frame(grp = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 3),
                 time = as.POSIXct("2017-06-05 12:00:00") + c(c(0, 1, 11), c(0, 1, 11) * 60, c(0, 1, 11) * 60 * 60, c(0, 1, 11) * 60 * 60 * 24))
`

Comment: @Henrik Agree, thank you! Now, is it a bug and how do I report bug for `dplyr`?

Comment: It's not a bug in `dplyr`, it's how `difftime` works. I think the relevant part of the help text is "If `units = "auto"`, a suitable set of units is chosen, _the largest possible_ [...] in which all the absolute differences are greater than one."

Comment: @Henrik, How do I provide units to `diff` function?

Comment: @Henrik Also `diff(ts$Cl_Date)` seems to be fine, no funny units selection

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ts <- ts %>% group_by(MDN) %>% arrange(Cl_Date) %>%
  mutate(time_diff_2 = as.numeric(Cl_Date-lag(Cl_Date), units = 'mins'))
```

Convert the time difference to a numeric value. You can use `units` argument to make the return values consistent.

Answer (score 2):

According to @hadley [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2059#issuecomment-238653698), the solution is to use lubridate instead of relying on base R.

This would be something like:

```r
ts %>% 
  group_by(MDN) %>% 
  arrange(Cl_Date) %>%
  mutate(as.duration(Cl_Date %--% lag(Cl_Date)))
```