# Difference in datetime objects produces unexpected result when used on a grouped tibble

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, posixct

I have a dataframe (or tibble) where each row has a POSIXct object in column `datetime`. I would like to group this df by column `event` and then calculate the duration of each event using the difference between the earliest and latest datetime for that event. Using dplyr::group_by(event) causes the base R time difference to produce an incorrect result.

Using tidy syntax and dplyr, I can filter the dataframe by event and get the result I expect.  However, using group_by to calculate the duration for each event in the dataframe, the time difference produced is incorrect.

Strangely, it is the same numerical value but the units are incorrect.

```r
library(dplyr)

df = structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1113573660, 1115025600, 
                                           1120784400, 1120788060, 1120791600, 1120795200, 1120798800, 1120802400, 
                                           1120806000, 1120809600, 1120813200, 1120816800, 1120820460, 1120824000, 
                                           1120827600, 1120831200, 1120834860, 1120838400, 1120842000, 1120860060, 
                                           1121034660, 1121113800, 1121121600, 1121122200, 1121122800, 1121482800, 
                                           1121486400, 1121490000, 1121493660, 1121497260, 1121504460, 1121508000, 
                                           1121511600, 1121515200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
                    event = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                              3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                    -34L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(datetime = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                     AnimalID = NA_integer_, DOP = NA_integer_, SV = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                     HU = NA_integer_, Sex = NA_integer_, in_core = NA_integer_, exit_event = NA_integer_
                                                                                                    ), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = "data.frame")
df = df %>% as_tibble()

head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   datetime            event
#>   <dttm>              <dbl>
#> 1 2005-04-15 07:01:00     1
#> 2 2005-05-02 02:20:00     2
#> 3 2005-07-07 18:00:00     3
#> 4 2005-07-07 19:01:00     3
#> 5 2005-07-07 20:00:00     3
#> 6 2005-07-07 21:00:00     3

# correct result
df %>% 
  filter(event == 3) %>%
  summarise(event = first(event), 
            duration = max(datetime) - min(datetime)) 
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   event duration
#>   <dbl> <drtn>  
#> 1     3 16 hours

# correct result
df %>% 
  group_by(event) %>% 
  summarise(duration = difftime(max(datetime), min(datetime), 
                                units = "secs")) %>%
  filter(event == 3)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   event duration  
#>   <dbl> <drtn>    
#> 1     3 57600 secs

# incorrect result
df %>% 
  group_by(event) %>% 
  summarise(duration = max(datetime) - min(datetime)) %>%
  filter(event == 3)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   event duration
#>   <dbl> <drtn>  
#> 1     3 16 secs
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9000)</sup>

No errors are returned, but the results of the last `duration` calculation should be either "16 hours" or "57600 secs". Instead, it is "16 secs"

Comment: At a quick guess, I think `max(datetime) - min(datetime)` is using `difftime(t1,t2, units="auto")` and combining different units - specify the units manually like you've done with `difftime` or force back `as.numeric(max(datetime) - min(datetime), units="secs")`

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks. Still doesn't make sense to me why it would combine different units, and when doing so why it would translate "16 hours" into "16 secs" rather than "57600 secs". You are correct though that using difftime with unit="auto" produces the incorrect result.

Comment: I'm not sure why it does that, but I can confirm a basic combination of concatenating 2 difftimes does work outside of a `group_by` scenario - e.g.: `c( as.difftime(1,units="secs"), as.difftime(1,units="hours") )` gives 1 sec and 3600 secs appropriately.

Comment: That df structure you start with is kind of weird. Look at `str(df)` and `attributes(df)` before the construction of a tibble. I'm guessing it was build from something else but didn't quite get assembled properly.

Comment: This looks to be discussed here previously - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377637/time-difference-between-rows-in-r-dplyr-different-units and has bug discussions here https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2059 and https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2432

Comment: @42- I used `structure()` to construct the dataframe just for this reprex. That was generated from a dataframe in my code using: `my_data %>% deparse() %>% clipr::write_clip()`

Comment: Passing a data structure to deparse looks pretty strange to my eyes.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks for finding this. I searched but did not find those issues! unfortunately hadley's answer seems to be that you can't use base time functions...

Comment: @jmw - looks like it also stings *data.table* too - `df[, max(datetime) - min(datetime), by=event]` , and for that matter base R itself - `aggregate(datetime ~ event, data = df, FUN=function(x) max(x) - min(x) )` Specifying the `units=` manually seems like a defensive move to me.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks. I was going to post an answer but I guess I should post it in the other question. Hadley's lubridate solution would be something like:`df %>% 
  group_by(event) %>% 
  summarise(duration = as.duration(interval(min(datetime), max(datetime))))`